# Applying function for manipulating RGB values of an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I would like to apply a self-defined RGB-based function for manipulating an image. My current solution works but is very slow:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load Data and get RBG values
im = Image.open(file_name).convert('RGB')
pixels = np.array(im)
s = pixels.shape
p = pixels.reshape((s[0]*s[1], s[2]))

# Apply Funtion (Subtraction + Max Operator)
p = np.array([[rgb[0], max(rgb[1] - rgb[1]*0.5, 0), rgb[2]] for i, rgb in enumerate(p)])

# Generate Image
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(p.reshape(s)))
img.save(file_name + '_new.png')
```

Comment: Surely `0.5 * pixels[1]` is easier and maybe faster than `pixels[1] - 0.5 * pixels[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

The following vectorized code will give an identical output:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load Data and get RBG values
im = Image.open(file_name).convert('RGB')
pixels = np.array(im)

# Apply Funtion (Subtraction + Max Operator)
pixels[:, :, 1] = np.maximum(pixels[:, :, 1]-0.5*pixels[:, :, 1], 0)

# Generate Image
img = Image.fromarray(pixels)
img.save(file_name + '_new.png')
```

I tested both versions with a `(400, 400, 3)` PNG image. Your initial solution takes about 1.2 seconds, whereas my code needs about 0.85 seconds. So, even your initial code is not that slow, from my point of view. Maybe for larger images, the difference will (also) increase.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** Ok, I did another test with a `(8239, 1349, 3)` PNG image. Your code needs 79.8 seconds, my (still) about 0.85 seconds. So, yes, the vectorized code seems way faster. ;-)

Comment: your code is much faster - on my computer for `(600, 800, 3) ` it needs 0.22 seconds and OP code needs 8 seconds.